# Adding a new document to a separate index using Elasticsearch processors

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro, opensearch

Is there a way to populate a separate index when I index some document(s)?

Let's assume I have something like:

```
PUT person/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Jonh Doe",
  "languages": ["english", "spanish"]
}

PUT person/_doc/2
{
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "languages": ["english", "russian"]
}
```

What I want is that every time a person is added, a language is added to a *language* index.

Something like:

```
GET languages/_search
```

would give:

```
...
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "languages",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "russian",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "value" : "russian"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "languages",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "english",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "value" : "english"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "languages",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "spanish",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "value" : "spanish"
    }
  }
...
```

Thinking of pipelines, but I don't see any processor that allow such a thing.

Maybe the answer is to create a custom processor. I have one already, but not sure how could I insert a document in a separate index there.

---

Update: Use [transforms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html) as described in @Val answer works, and seems to be the right answer indeed...

However, I am using *Open Distro for Elasticsearch* and transforms are not available there. Some alternative solution that works there would be greatly appreciated :)

---

Update 2: Looks like *OpenSearch* is replacing *Open Distro for Elasticsearch*. And there is a [transform api](https://opensearch.org/docs/im-plugin/index-transforms/transforms-apis/) \o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each document entering an ingest pipeline cannot be cloned or split like it is doable in Logstash for instance. So from a single document, you cannot index two documents.

However, just after indexing your person documents, it's definitely possible to hit the [`_transform` API endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html) and create the `languages` index from the `person` one:

First create the transform:

```
PUT _transform/languages-transform
{
  "source": {
    "index": "person"
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "language": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "languages.keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "count": {
        "value_count": {
          "field": "languages.keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "languages",
    "pipeline": "set-id"
  }
}
```

You also need to create the pipeline that will set the proper ID for your language documents:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/set-id
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_id",
        "value": "{{language}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can start the transform:

```
POST _transform/languages-transform/_start
```

And when it's done you'll have a new index called `languages` whose content is

```
GET languages/_search
=>
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "languages",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "english",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "count" : 4,
      "language" : "english"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "languages",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "russian",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "count" : 2,
      "language" : "russian"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "languages",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "spanish",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "count" : 2,
      "language" : "spanish"
    }
  }
]
```

Note that you can also set that transform on schedule so that it runs regularly, or you can run it manually whenever suits you, to rebuild the languages index.

---

OpenSearch has its own [_transform](https://opensearch.org/docs/im-plugin/index-transforms/transforms-apis/) API. It works slightly different, the transform could be created this way:

```
PUT _plugins/_transform/languages-transform
{
  "transform": {
    "enabled": true,
    "description": "Insert languages",
    "schedule": {
      "interval": {
        "period": 1,
        "unit": "minutes"
      }
    },
    "source_index": "person",
    "target_index": "languages",
    "data_selection_query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "page_size": 1,
    "groups": [{
      "terms": {
        "source_field": "languages.keyword",
        "target_field": "value"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid we'll be using the "Open Distro for Elasticsearch" flavor. `_transform` cannot be used as it is part of `X-Pack` :(. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Nonetheless, I have tested it in a machine where I have the original Elasticsearch and it seems to work... except if I later add new people with new languages, they are not added :-/
Tried to `POST _transform/languages-transform/_start`, also `stop`, after adding the new persons, didn't work.

Comment: The post didn't mention Opendistro, but yes, it's only available in the official version of Elasticsearch

Comment: In order to pick up new people, you need to set that transform on `sync` in order to let it run on a regular schedule

Comment: Sync worked. Also realized Open distro is being replaced by OpenSearch, which has its own transform API. Edited answer to add OpenSearch solution and accepted. Looks like a correct answer both for Elasticsearch and OpenSearch.
Thanks!

Comment: Sad you lost 100 reputation points for nothing, though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to change your `_index` field name in the ingest pipeline:

```
{
  "description" : "sets the value of count to 1",
  "set": {
            "if": "[*your condition here*]",
            "field": "_index",
            "value": "languages",
            "override": true
        }
}
```

Comment: For what I've just tested, that would allow me to reroute documents to `languages` index. But if i do `GET person/_search`, documents are not there.
I want the original documents in the original index untouched, extracted information would go into the other index.

Comment: You can add it language and person index in value like “language,person”.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get the error: `Invalid index name [person,languages], must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]`

Comment: So in this case your best option would be to handle this logic in your application not in ES.